# What is the third letter in the Mishna Berura?

Tags: mishnah-berurah

In the standard editions of the Mishna Berura, I generally see three letters in the MB section.

Here’s what I know: (I think?)

**A** The big bold letter without the parentheses is the Seif of the Mechaber.

**(A)** The second letter (this one also bold and in parentheses) is the seif katan of the MB. So here you would say for example Siman 23, seif Katan 2. That would be the “Bet” in bold and parentheses, right?

Here is what I do not know:

(Rashi script: A) Here is where my question lies: there is a third letter in Rashi script, not bold, and in parenthesis. What is this letter there for?

Comment: It would be great if you could include a picture of an example page with the markings in question highlighted. It's hard for me to understand what you are referring to

Comment: It's for the Shaarei Tzyion which is on the bottom of page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Rashi script letters in parenthesis indicate the number in the Shaar Hatziun footnote on the bottom of the page.